# How can I measure the time of imports in QML file?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

I want to profile my QML and measure the time taken by all the imports of one given QML file.

I know there is a [debug timer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-debugging.html#timer) in QtQuick. But I don't see how I can profile the import part, not even the loading part.
Is there a way to measure that?

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use the [QML Profiler](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-qml-performance-monitor.html) for this. In particular, you should take a look at the Compiling and Creating event categories:

https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-qml-performance-monitor.html#understanding-the-data

Comment: I would have preferred something in the code but I can already see that *Compiling* time is increasing if I add imports, *Creating* remains the same. It's half of the information because *Compiling* is both the imports and the content of the QML, not just the import time, but it's already a good indicator thanks !